# Error Trying To Upload Image File In ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, web

I have the following asp.net C# code to upload an image, and when I try to run it and select the file to upload, it does not recognize that I have selected a file to upload, so I get the message "file not uploaded successfully. I get the following error when trying.  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I believe I have to add code, to instantiate.  I am new to this, and I believe I do not have the correct syntax. I have a data entry form where the File Upload.  Can someone tell me what I need, I think I need to add a declaration, as in Line 3 (with  ******), but what I have may not be correct if it is not setting the file I am trying to upload, the debugger shows no file, although I am selecting one.  Thanks.

See code below

```
protected void ButImg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ******FileUpload fileImg = (FileUpload)this.FindControl("fileImg");*****
            
            if (fileImg.HasFile)
            {
                string imgfile = Path.GetFileName(fileImg.PostedFile.FileName);
                string savePath = Path.Combine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagesFolder"], imgfile);
                fileImg.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("UsrImage/"+ imgfile));
                _connstr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString;

                /* Save file to Ticket Attachments folder */
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(savePath))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(savePath);
                }
                SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(_connstr);
                sqlconn.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(_procUpdateImage);
                sqlcomm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlcomm.Connection = sqlconn;
                sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UsrID", this.txtUsrID.Text);
                sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageName", imgfile);
                sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImagePath", "Images/" + imgfile);
                sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UsrID", _UsrName);

                sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                LitImg.Text = "Image saved successfully";
                sqlconn.Close();
                fileImg.SaveAs(savePath);
            }
            else
            {
                LitImg.Text = "Image not saved successfully";
            }


        }


.aspx web form for Upload control 
<td class="tdSingle">Usr Image</td>
            <td class="tdSingle">
         <asp:FileUpload ID="fileImg" runat="server"></asp:FileUpload><br/>
            <asp:Button ID="ButImg" runat="server" Text="Image Save" OnClick="ButImg_Click" ></asp:Button><br/>
                <p>
                <asp:Literal ID="LitImg" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                </p>
</td>
```